# Open a link in a popup window

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the normal jqGrid. I have a column which I am displaying as a hyperlink in the grid. On hovering over the column item , I do see the url. on right click and open, the link does open. What I want is, on click of the link I want the page to open in a popup. At present it does nothing on click.

```
jQuery("#TestGrid").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  height: 250,
  autowidth: true,
  colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Date', 'Status'],
  colModel: [{
      name: 'ID',
      index: 'ID',
      width: 300,
      formatter: function(cellValue, options, rowdata) {
        if (some_condition != "")
          return "<a href= 'my_url' title='Details'</a>"
        else
          return "<a></a>"
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Name',
      index: 'Name',
      width: 300
    },
    {
      name: 'Date',
      index: 'Date',
      width: 300
    },
    {
      name: 'Status',
      index: 'Status',
      width: 300
    },
  ],
  multiselect: true,
});
```

Comment: You're missing the `>`

Comment: Use `target="_blank"` in the anchor, just like you would in ordinary HTML.

Comment: _blank opens it in a new tab. I want it to open in a popup.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have any control over the choice between tabs and windows, that's a user preference.

Comment: For the same, the result my SP returns is "10-06-2019 07:00" in this format. What I see on UI is  "2019-06-10T07:00:00" format. Pls suggest how I could get it in "13/06/2019 07:51" format.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function to format dates how you like.